# Copy a website for offline view without JavaScript (script tags in html and .js externals)

Tags: javascript, html, wget, httrack

I'm trying to copy a website for offline view without any dependencies.

I want to copy the HTML without SCRIPT tags (javascript specifically) and without external scripts (.js).

Been trying to do that with `WGET --ignore-tags` and HTTrack and it didn't work as expected. Scripts are copied as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

Calling Chrome in [Headless mode](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/04/headless-chrome) e.g. `chrome --headless --disable-gpu --dump-dom https://www.chromestatus.com/` will dump the HTML of a rendered DOM without any JavaScript.

[This post](https://fettblog.eu/scraping-with-puppeteer/) describes how a crawler was built using Headless Chrome and Puppeteer.